# Upload Image Form and Another Fill-up Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

What I have is a form with details like name, address...and another separate upload profile pic form. And I want to get that (optional) uploaded picture when the "parent" (separate) form is submitted. 
**Right now they work like this:**
Uploaded pic is sent through `.ajaxSubmit()` to process_uploaded_image.php. Then it gets processed, resized, and the new picture is made within a "dump/temp" folder. I could return it in `success: function(data)`, in the form of data that could be the echoed `$image_path_and_name` or as an `<img src="$image_path_and_name"/>`. I made it this way - that, is having a temp image - since 
(1) I want to let the user view what he just uploaded (remember I already have it returned path or img element to jquery and I could place it anywhere I want), and 
(2) the uploaded image isn't final, not until the "parent" form finalizes the registration. And it is still a temp image after all.
So, *the problem is*: **I want to access that uploaded image, and "bring it along"  with the "parent" form when it gets submitted**...how can I do that exactly? Technically it isn't a parent form, since I know a form within form is not allowed. But it is tied up and under that parent form logically. I would be thankful for any help, but if possible, I would appreciate it even more if you could consider my present scenario so I won't have to start from scratch again. Thanks again.
**My idea:** (please let me know how feasible this is...and/or guideline on how I could do #1)
1. "reconstruct" or copy that file from ajax-jquery returned (data) of `$image_path_and_name` string or `<img src="$image_path_and_name"/>`, place it in final upload folder.**<---THIS IS WHERE I'M STUMPED!** I couldn't just use `move_uploaded_file()`, can I?
2. Since, from this point everything's final..I could save its file path to my database, along with other form info.
 
3. empty the dump/temp folder.

Comment: what problem are you facing in copy??

Comment: how can I copy? I couldn't just use `move_uploaded_file()` since it is in the form of jquery string from `$image_file_path_and_name` or maybe I could chop this off to string path and string name - but it still isn't the file itself...or can I? That's how `move_uploaded_file()` work right? You need the uploaded file itself?

Comment: php has copy function, so if you have filepath you can use it to copy

Comment: Aha, thanks. I guess I can stick with my idea, then? There's nothing wrong about it? Maybe this could work after all...hidden input field from Haocheng, and your copy() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is that using a iframe for upload, and using JavaScript like this in the return page of the iframe

```
echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.insert('". $WHAT_YOU_WANT . "');</script>");
```

and the function `insert` is defined in the parent page, and can insert the string into the where you want. `obj_ta` is the target textfield, or something else.

```
//A simple input
function insert(str) {
    obj_ta.value = str;
}

//A textfield which accept some other user inputs
function insert(str) {
var startPos = obj_ta.selectionStart,
    val = obj_ta.value;
obj_ta.value = val.substring(0, startPos) + str + val.substring(startPos, obj_ta.value.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure I get what this does exactly. Pls correct me: so I would have to have a hidden text field within the "parent" form, that value would be supplied with the jquery data (from ajax php of `$image_path_and_name`). So it gets included when "parent" form is submitted? Is that it?

Comment: My solution is that the pic is uploaded with an `iframe`, and the `parent` object of the iframe is the main page. As you said, the prepared hidden field will be submitted when the main form is submitted.

Comment: I guess that could work for the path_and_name string, and I could now store it in database. Thanks a lot. But I guess that also means that there's no longer a temp folder? I'd be using the image file itself...and no more storing to a permanent location for uploaded images, and cleaning up of temp images from temp folder?

Comment: On the other hand...I can combine Sibu's suggestion and yours. Copy it to another folder, then knowing the string...I could place the value to hidden field to be submitted later on. Thanks.

Comment: The copy can be done in the request of iframe, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: this is exactly what I am trying to do...  were there ever any examples/links posted for this solution?  I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: @whispers Sorry it's from an internal site, I can't show you the complete example.

Comment: @Haocheng

no worries!  I finally got everything figured out and it is working good so far.

My last obstacle (now) is that I need to be able to offer an 'edit page' so that users can edit their posted message (which is also working) but I cant figure out yet how to allow the users to update their attached images from the initial/original post.  Any suggestions?

I am currently just listing out the originally uploaded images as links.. and adding a 'browse' button next to each link (but it has no connection to each other so far... so Im not sure how I can have it replace the current image)

Answer (score 1):

Make two folders one as temp and other final....... and after uploading of image place the name of file into a hidden field in main form........ then while sending the data in database move the image to final folder and the name(from hidden field) into the database..

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm going to do now. Thanks for confirming. Voted up!

Comment: for moving files you can use if( is_file($source) )
  {
                rename($source,$destination);
  }

Comment: I think I remember something like this in cmd prompt, rename to another location means a copy, right? Or does it work more like cut? Thanks, good info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the file location and after the user validates and confirms the image you can use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function to copy from your temporary folder to main folder.so it will be like

```
1) copy($file, $newfile)
```

2) Update the database about new path.

3) Unlink the file from old path.

```
unlink($file);
```

More about [Unlinking a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: You've been very helpful. I would share best answer if I could. Voted up, and you have my sincere thanks.

Comment: @Fred gracias, if you have any prob just ask

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking to do! (no plug-ins..etc)

I want to upload 1-10 images (outside of  my main form) and have the returned 1-10 file name/paths returned to my MAIN/Parent form (in hidden fields is fine!).. so that when the user submits the main form, the file path/names all get saved to a database with the rest of the MAIN form data 

The reason for this is to not allow any image upload timeouts/errors interfere with the main/parent form data posting (not loose their message)

Are there any working example or links?